# Why can't I play sounds more than once using HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

This is how the sound is "stored":

```
<audio id = "hammer" src="res/sounds/Building/hammer.wav"></audio>
```

In the actual game (which I use sounds for), I use this to play the sound:

```
   function playSound(soundid)
   {
        document.getElementById(soundid).currentTime = 0;
        document.getElementById(soundid).play();
   }
```

But the sound plays only the first time, and never again!
I tried resetting the "currentTime" in the console to 0, but I literally get this:

```
>document.getElementById("hammer").currentTime = 0
0
>document.getElementById("hammer").currentTime
0.340...
```

Why is this happening, how do I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps it's the wav file? This works just fine for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/xWFuq/. (Don't mind the sound file; it was the shortest one I was able to find.)

Comment: But how can that be? Anyway, maybe it's my computer's fault, I'll run it on a server and test it on another one...

Comment: I don't know; sometimes my Chrome all of a sudden refuses to play any `<video>` anymore (not yet tested with `<audio>`); even the UI controls kind of freeze. This is all resolved when I restart Chrome.

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers?

Comment: I didn't test it in any browsers other than Chrome. Wait a second, I will. EDIT: my Firefox version doesn't support HTML5...

Comment: I just checked on another computer, it doesn't work there, as well.

Comment: Download fresh firefox, opera and ie9. If it still does not work - return back. (Also, _Saying that Firefox does not support HTML5 .. will make people ignore you._)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See [this slide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1HK947ywibadLLdbAAv5SBYjQ22UER7gbJyXss85GLmg/edit#slide=id.g1437efb_0_28) and the preceding three slides of [Evan Wallace and Justin Ardini's presentation on html5 game dev](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1HK947ywibadLLdbAAv5SBYjQ22UER7gbJyXss85GLmg/edit#slide=id.g1437efb_0_28).

For all the resources to make some awesome games, part of their talk: http://madebyevan.com/gamedevclass/

> Audio still doesn't work consistently across all browsers, as of right now:
>
> - An element must be reloaded in Chrome or it will only play once
> - An element must not be reloaded in Firefox or there will be a delay

```
function playSoundEvent() {
  if (window.chrome) elems[index].load()
  elems[index].play()
  index = (index + 1) % elems.length
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great info! I'll test that function out and I'll probably accept your answer.

Comment: (I haven't tried it myself, but these guys are total bosses, so I'd expect their stuff to be correct :)

Comment: Why does it work like so? Isn't it a little retarded that I need to redownload whole audio file to play it second time?

Comment: @user2486570 Yes but you can use "Cache-Control" http header for caching - so the file won't be downloaded again

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue recently with an html5. Worked everywhere except safari.
Using  load() before calling play() solved this problem. It also helps to make sure that sound effects do not overlap with heavy clickers when event-handlers trigger sounds.

```
Here what I used
<audio id="sound-one" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://myurl/foo.mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://myurl/foo.ogg"></source>
</audio>


<a href="#" id="navigation-id">click here</a>  



Jquery
$("#navigation-id") //this attached is to an element on the page
.mouseover(function() {
    sound-one.load();                               
    sound-one.play();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A few months before I faced the same issue while developing a Piano in HTML5. When a key was pressed again and again I had to stop, rewind and play the audio on each key press.  I used the same code written in this question which worked in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome. In Chrome it didn't play again. Finally I had to modify the code to make it work. Added one listener for the event `onseeked`, then set `currentTime = 0` and in the event handler invoked `play`. This worked for me. Similarly I had to wait for the event of one action before giving next action in many places. It was an old version of Chrome. Later I found out that even some versions of Browsers support Audio, the way each one supports is slightly different. This difference won't be visible if we simply put an audio tag and play the audio, but will experience when we try to control the audio using Javascript.  Anyways its all about  older versions of Browsers, its much much better in all latest versions. So please check in the latest version of Chrome ( Even my piano worked in Chrome 10 without the code modification ) and regarding the audio format, I would suggest you to keep mp3 and ogg files of your audio instead of single wav file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this post in the future, the audio tag is really not a great way to do game audio.

I'd highly recommend taking the time to learn the [WebAudio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API) instead.