# Possible to play a sound twice in a row in html 5?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to build a simon game where the user must remember the sounds being played in the right sequence.  I've wired up the audio and it fires correctly when the element is clicked. However, the audio will not play the same sound twice in a row unless you click twice. In other words, I cannot have the computer simulate pressing the button two times in a row.

This is a simplified except from my js file:

**Attempt 1** (calling the function twice):

```
...
var redButton    = document.getElementById("red");
var audioRed     = document.getElementById("audio-red");

redButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   createNewSeq();
});
...

var createNewSeq = function () {
  audioRed.play();
  audioRed.play();
};
```

audioRed will only fire one time.

**Attempt 2** (trying to force a reload with calling the load function):

```
var createNewSeq = function () {
  audioRed.play();
  audioRed.load();
  audioRed.play();
};
```

Same issue - only plays a single time.

**Attempt 3** (re-building element): another attempt I thought of is literally re-building and re-loading the audio tag on every firing of a method but that seems ridiculous and laughably inefficient.

**Attempt 4** (create a delay from like setTimeout): Again, I know this is a terrible and inaccurate but if the problem is timing it's possible this could prevent the same thing being called at the same time obscuring if it's been called or not.

**Attempt 5** (changing the source of the audio element to force a reload): I thought that if you change the source of the element than change it back, it would force it to view that second change as distinct from the first.

Is audio really accessible to a beginner or do you need to work with streams and buffers for it to really work?

Comment: There's some good stuff here that might be useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733330/why-cant-i-play-sounds-more-than-once-using-html5-audio-tag

Comment: I took a look at that before I posted and didn't see something that solves my problem.  I'm currently trying to force a redraw of the element but it just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @user3162553, you want it to play second time once the first time is finished right?

Comment: That's correct @mido22 and I think that's the approach I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Media Events to trigger on the [`ended` event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#mediaevents). If you think about it, you're trying to play, load, then play all at the same time. It's like saying, "Play, load, play!" without waiting for it to finish.

Note, I don't know browser support for Media Events (the demo doesn't work in IE11 due to access restrictions on the file source, but it works in Chrome and Firefox Latest).

Demo (plays twice on button `click`):

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Sample_of_%22Another_Day_in_Paradise%22.ogg" preload="auto"></audio>
<button type='button' id='test'>Play Sound</button>
<span id='played'>0</span>

var audiotag = document.getElementById('audiotag1'),
    test = document.getElementById('test'),
    played = document.getElementById('played'),
    times_played = 0,
    max_plays = 2;

test.addEventListener('click', function() {
    audiotag.play();

    times_played++;
    played.textContent = 'Play #: ' + times_played;
});

audiotag.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    console.log('run again', times_played);

    if (times_played >= max_plays) {
        times_played = 0;
        played.textContent = 'Play #: ' + times_played;

        return;
    }

    audiotag.currentTime = 0;
    audiotag.play();

    times_played++;
    played.textContent = 'Play #: ' + times_played;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7xybLus/3/

Comment: Thanks for the demo - this is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't know why it never occurred to me to be able to set an event listener for the ended event of audio.